# java ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert a timestamp coming from a JSON API to a relative time span string like this:

```
try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
                Date date = sdf.parse(item.getTimeStamp());
                long milliseconds = date.getTime();

                CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                        milliseconds,
                        System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The timestamp comes back in JSON like this: `2014-07-01T00:05:20Z`

I'm throwing the exception for `Unparseable date`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Z` expects timezone value, change your pattern to and you don't need `SSS` since you don't have milliseconds in input

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

Comment: Thank you! My date is now being parsed and displayed. It's still not converting to the `timeAgo` format though. Any idea why?

Comment: Try changing  `SECOND_IN_MILLIS` to `FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE`